# How can I build the following UI item?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a view similar to the one on the screenshot.
The question is what is the first element(the one with label and chevron)
When I tap on it, it behaves like a table cell(on the screenshot I captured it in tapped state). Thank you!

[image]

**UPDATE**
I ended up creating 2 sections and then checked for index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me exactly like a standard `UITableView` cell, with `cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator` and the background color etc. changed of course.

Comment: Looks like it was table view controller with 2 sections. The first one's with static cell and without header.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly looks like the standard table view cell, but you could easily implement this with a custom view (NIB) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can build this view with `UITableViewDelegate` like this:

1. Make a button in the cell and set this image to the button.
2. Set `yourButton.isHidden = true` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
3. Set `yourButton.isHidden = false` in `didSelectRowAtIndextPath`

That's it.